# Daily tasks in Apache Server

Tags: c, apache, scheduled-tasks, apache-modules

I'm writing some apache (2.2) modules in C and I'm pretty new at it, so I was wondering:

I want to make a daily task. One that will read a file and insert it's data into a list.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). They allow you to run a command at chosen intervals.

Comment: I understand.
But is there a way to have the tasks be executed by the apache server? 
Since I want the task to be updating a static list from a file every day. A list that the server should use for incoming requests.
Or can the Cronjobs help me with that as well?
If there is a Apache command that can do that, that is.
Thanks for the quick reply by the way.

Comment: Can you update your list through a HTTP request? An easy way out would be to set up a cronjob that does `wget` to your own server, making Apache call your module. This is probably by far not the nicest way, since it's quite ugly. I don't know what Apache modules can and can't do.

Comment: I think I'd rather try to find a solution that uses the Apache modules. 
I thought of checking the date on every request and then calling the task if a day has past. But THATS ugly.
But your solution is quite elegent. I guess I'll use it if I get stuck. Thanks!